# When does Spark assign partition to worker for map()?

Tags: apache-spark

I was wondering when Spark assign partition to each worker during a map() operation. I'm guessing it might be one of below two options:

1. Spark assign all partitions to workers before computation starts
2. Spark assign one partitions to each worker at the very beginning. And after each worker finished processing its partition, it got a new partition for processing, and so on.

Can please share what strategy Spark is using here?

Thanks

Comment: More precuse I think you mean Executors. Also, there can be a limit to the total number of concurrent Executors per Job.

Comment: @thebluephantom, think when we assign multiple cores to one executor, executor can work on the same amount of partitions in parallel. That's why I used "worker" instead of "executor" in my question. Is there a more appropriate term for "worker"? Agree that there is a limit to total number of executors.

Comment: Point taken, Sir, but I like to be strict...